# What does off street in this rent house ad really mean?

Tags: word-meaning

> Garage and Parking
>
> - Parking: parking space, off street

What does "off street" mean? And the difference is between "parking space" and "parking lot" and "off street" ?

Comment: Note by the way we say *What does X **really** mean?* only when we suspect that X does not mean what it (or he/she/it) **appears** to mean - that is, when you suspect that you have been misled.

Comment: Helpful dictionary entry [here](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/off-street-parking). This looks like it's referring to something that isn't a concern in rural areas, but is a huge concern in cities where parking is scarce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means a space where you may park your car:

- not an entire 'lot', which is a large tract of land where many cars may be parked, but a single space for one car
- and not 'on the street': that is, it is not at the curb (which is public, so anybody driving down the street might park there) but on the property itself.

Comment: Also, since "garage" is mentioned in the header but not the text, we can assume that it is an outside spot, fully exposed to the elements, rather than being inside a heated or unheated section of building, or even under a roof.